# Как сортировать массив с датами/временем?

Tags: javascript

У меня есть такой массив

```
let startTime = ['9:00','9:30','10:00','10:30','11:00','11:30','12:00','12:30','13:00']
```

если

```
let start = '10:00'
```

тогда я буду получить новый массив

```
let endTime = ['10:30','11:00','11:30','12:00','12:30','13:00']
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
let array = ["08:00", "09:00", "10:10", "10:30", "10:50", "11:30", "11:50", "12:00"],
    min = "09:00",
    max = "11:30",
    result = array.filter(a => a > min && a < max);

console.log(result);
```

Соответственно, для работы только в одну сторону используйте:

```js
let array = ["08:00", "09:00", "10:10", "10:30", "10:50", "11:30", "11:50", "12:00"],
    min = "09:00",
    result = array.filter(a => a > min);

console.log(result);
```

Ну и аналогично в обратную сторону.

Исходник ответа: [javascript - Filter array of dates - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47355211/4772782)

Comment: не надо написать

Comment: let min = "09:00"

Comment: У меня не работает

Comment: @АрамГаспарян отредактировал ответ, можете запустить и убедиться в работоспособности